# Karma + Jasmine + Angular2 + Webpack: coreTesting.setBaseTestProviders is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, karma-jasmine

Trying to set up some test system via [this](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-components-in-angular-2-with-jasmine) article. It's all more or less understandable, but I've got an error which I currently can't resolve.

My `karma.entry.js`:

```
require('es6-shim');
require('reflect-metadata');
require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');


const browserTesting = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');
const coreTesting = require('@angular/core/testing');


coreTesting.setBaseTestProviders(
   browserTesting.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
   browserTesting.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
);

const context = require.context('..\\srs\\', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 2000;
```

Running "npm test" results in error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: coreTesting.setBaseTestProviders is not a function
at webpack:///karma/karma.entry.js:15:0 <- karma.entry.js:61
```

As far as I can guess, `require('@angular/core/testing');` doesn't return an object I need. I've seen the similar topics here but so far nothing works.
I understand, that somewhere the dependency is missing but can't pinpoint where exactly.

My `karma.conf.js`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (config) => {
config.set({
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    files: [
        '../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
        'karma.entry.js'
    ],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    phantomJsLauncher: {
        exitOnResourceError: true
    },
    preprocessors: {
        'karma.entry.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    reporters: ['dots'],
    singleRun: false,
    webpack: require('..\\webpack\\webpack.test'),
    webpackServer: {
        noInfo: true
    }
});
};
```

My `package.json` seems to have all necessary dependencies:

```
{
 ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^3.2.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.24.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
     "karma": "^1.3.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
     "typings": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

Could someone please kindly inform me where exactly I have misconfigured the whole thing?

Comment: Have you seen Changelog 2.0.0-rc.5 (2016-08-09)? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/aa4bd14b3f3ddc7a08192589a9bb3931edf426e9/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc5-2016-08-09 `setBaseTestProviders is deprecated and only supports platformProviders that are predefined by Angular. Use 'TestBed.initTestEnvironment' instead.`

Comment: yep. thnx. Just found it

Answer (score 2):

The testing API changed multiple times. The current version of the testing entry file is available in the repository [linked from this article](https://github.com/gonzofish/semaphore-ng2-webpack/blob/master/karma/karma.entry.js).

Basically, what you should now do is to use the exposed TestBed class from the `core/testing` module, rather than directly calling the now removed `setBaseTestProviders` method.

```
...
coreTesting.TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
coreTesting.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
    browserTesting.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    browserTesting.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
```

The TestBed is a class that deals with requirements of the testing environment. You can learn more about it in the [Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I have used a deprecated method.